# Why are monocrystalline solar cells more efficient than polycrystalline solar cells?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

What causes monocrystalline silicon to be more efficient than polycrystalline silicon in the production of a solar cell?

I have read [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/ngvu76/why_is_monocrystalline_solar_cells_more_efficient/) on Reddit:

> In general, single crystal is always better than polycrystalline. The grain boundaries between the crystallites add scattering centers which will reduce the efficiency. Remember that in a perfect single crystal at 0 K, there is no scattering. So the fewer defects, the closer to the ideal properties of the material you can get

Is this explanation up above correct? Can you explain these to me? It is not clear.

> In monocrystalline silicon or single crystalline silicon one can observe long range order this leads to greater scope to move electron with out any collisions so that conversion efficiency that is solar to electrical energy efficiency will be very high and material will be continuous and edges can be cut cleanly where as above said all are not possible in polycrystalline silicon or multycrystalline silicon.So, in view of conversion efficiency one has to prefer the monocrystalline silicon where as by keeping cost in view then we have to prefer polycrystalline silicon for solar panels.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: This is something has to do with "Solid-State" physics, right? Can somebody explain please?

Comment: *I have read this answer.* Where? Please link to both quotes.

Comment: @G.Smith Don't know where I got the second answer from. I put the first one tho.

Comment: Fewer defects, less carrier recombination. These questions are all solar cell basics.

Comment: @Jon Custer is purity of a solar cell related to those explanations I quoted above also? I have read that monocrystalline solar cells also more pure than monocrystalline solar cells, that's why I am asking.

Comment: 1st answer is correct (albeit it could be more detailed), 2nd sounds somewhat unclear

Comment: Semiconductor grade silicon is semiconductor grade silicon, broadly speaking. The process to purify has been the same since the 1940s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grain boundaries introduce resistance to the flow of electrical current, thereby wasting a portion of the solar cell's electrical output power as heat before it ever gets out of the cell and into your wires. To minimize this effect, you must use single-crystal silicon. But since this is more expensive than polycrystalline silicon, you must include your budget constraints in your proposed use model. If you are cost-limited, you will probably end up with polycrystalline. If you are performance-limited, probably single crystal.